# How to resolve "CA0001 : unknown error while running code analysis" in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

while building solution i got error

**CA0001: An unknown error occurred while running Code Analysis**

error does not show the file name,line number or project name. I don't understand why this error is showing or how to resolve it.

Comment: We have even less information than you do. As it says, it's an *unknown error*. Look for clues in other output, etc, but we're not going to be able to help from here. If you could create a [mcve], there's a chance we could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Rule set in code analysis and this issue got fixed.
I changed the rule to **Microsoft managed recommended rules** previous rule was Microsoft all rules. I don't know what happened but this is just a work around
**EDIT**
project -> project properties -> Code Analysis -> Configure rule set
we can change rule set from here

Comment: Thanks for sharing the resolution, you can mark it as answer as it would be helpful to anyone who encounters similar issues.

Comment: I understand that you changed a rule, but where did you change it?

Comment: @KennethCarter project -> project properties -> code analysis -> configure rule set you can change rules from here